# How can we get our activity up?

Tags: discussion

As noted in area51:

[image]

We are dropping our daily questions by a lot recently:

[image]

Given that we have time before we reach 180 days in beta, what steps can we take to up our stats? How do we get more engagement from the community?

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine there's still quite a bit of marketing to be done. The only way I found out about the SE is by visiting the Discord, and even there it took some time to find the right channel.

So probably a few places it should be publicized:

1. solana.com developer portal
2. soldev.app as a resource
3. As a pinned announcement in the Discord (may already be in place)
4. Announced on the Podcast as a resource for developers
5. On blogs posting relevant tutorial content
6. Same for Youtubers

Thoughts?

Comment: These are all great places. We'll work on getting them there. How do we get people voting more too though?

Comment: I would say we just include it as part of the message. Like if one of the goals of the SO is to encourage voting we just say "We encourage users to vote on the best answers in order to help drive more engagement to this SO" or something like that.
I guess I'm thinking more it's not just dropping a link, but wrapping it in a message about why the SO exists and what it means to contribute in this space.